# Save Error: Entity is not org-accessible

Tags: apex, unit-test, controller

i have this issues when i try to save my method in a test class, when i delete this method from the class the error disappear.

```
@isTest
public with sharing class Test_xxx_Controller {
```

The error is in line 1, and my method is this:

```
static testMethod void checkA(){

    Account acc = new Account();

    acc.Name = 'Brown';
    acc.Surname__c = 'fdd';
    acc.Fiscal_Code__c = 'rssmrc90a15h703x';
    acc.XXX__c = '12345678910';
    acc.ZIP__c = '01234';
    acc.Address__c = 'street fff';
    insert acc;

    XXX__c bc= new XXX__c();

    bc.AAA__c = 'Test';
    bc.BBB__c = '42';
    bc.CCC__c = 'Street';
    bc.DDD__c ='Antstreet';                         
    bc.EEE__c = '5';
    insert bc;


}
```

Comment: Usually thrown due to a typo or incorrect reference to a custom object.

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4599/efficient-way-to-find-error-causing-save-error-entity-is-not-org-accessible?rq=1 It does often happen if you have custom object with a name that could be a standard object, but you've missed the __c in referring to your one e.g. Invoice instead of Invoice__c

Comment: I checked these __c and i have not. Is a strange error.

Comment: What is class XXX__c?  Do you still get the error if you comment out the second half of the function? (from declaring bc to the end)

Comment: You might be better off posting your code verbatim instead of modifying it, if that's what you've done here.

Comment: If you are not writing API name correctly then you will get this error, check for the API names of objects used.

Comment: Also check your class API version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it, only deleting the package on Eclipse and re-open it. The api name were right. Thank you to all !

Answer (score 2):

You'll get this error if you reference an object that's not enabled for some reason. For example, if Quotes are not enabled in your org, you'd get an error if you tried to deploy code that used Quotes. The specific code in your question would never fail to compile assuming that XXX__c, AAA__c, etc exists in your org. However, things like AccountShare don't exist when accounts are public read/write, AccountHistory doesn't exist if you're not tracking field history, etc.